# Reduce homology of $H_1(\mathbb{R}^n,x)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n>1$. My goal is to compute $H_1(\mathbb{R}^n,x)$. I write the exact sequence
$$H_1(\mathbb{R}^n)\to H_1(\mathbb{R}^n,x)\to \widetilde{H}_0(x)\to \widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
We have, $\widetilde{H}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong 0$, for all $p$, and I assume that $\widetilde{H}_0(x)\cong 0$ (?).
So
$ H_1(\mathbb{R}^n,x)\cong \widetilde{H}_0(x)\cong0.$ Is this correct? Is $\widetilde{H}_0(x)\cong 0$ correct? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: How did you compute $\tilde H_p(\mathbb R^n) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct, and you can actually compute $\tilde H_0(x) = 0$ directly from the definition of singular homology because there's only one $0-$simplex and one $1-$simplex in this space so all the relevant groups in the augmented chain complex $C_*(x)$ are finitely generated. It's a good exercise to get you more familiar with the definitions.